# Published mvc4 web application re-seeding/erasing db randomly

Tags: azure, asp.net-mvc-4

I have created a website using mvc4, everything working fine in the dev environment.

The site was running for about 6 hours (luckily only a few people had registered) and then the database reverted to the state it would be when the site was first published.

I had made a few changed to the site since it had gone live (just to the views) and those changes persisted, had the site somehow re-published itself, those changes wouldn't have stayed.

The changes I made as to how the db seeds were all from this post; http://kevin-junghans.blogspot.ie/2013/01/seeding-customizing-aspnet-mvc.html .

Any help would be great, I can't pin down the problem and don't want to put the site live again until I know that user accounts won't be deleted.

If there is any more specific information that would be useful for identifying the problem let me know.

Comment: What class does your database initializer inherit from? Did you keep it the same as in the article, DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges?

Comment: I set up the project the exact same as in the article. Initially using DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges.. I have since tried using CreateDatabaseIfNotExists to see if that would stop it, but I just republished and left it running over the weekend and the same thing has happened. Could I delete the database initializer and just create the database manually with the sql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up publishing the project including the database, than removing reference to initDb and recreating the database, then re-publishing.. And so far the issue hasn't happened again.